# JsRender. Nested loop by the object of top loop

Tags: jsrender

```
{{for players}}
   <tr>
    {{for ~root.players}}
        {{if index == #index}}
            <td>*</td>
        {{else}}
            <td>{{index}}+{{:#getIndex()}}</td>
        {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

I want to get access to #index of the top loop in nested loop by the players to compare top loop #index and nested loop #index. Maybe it is possible to access to top loop current item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of getting to parent views. See http://www.jsviews.com/#views: *get(type) method*, *Accessing "parent" data, from nested views*, etc.

For example you can create a contextual template parameter: `~index`

```
{{for players}}
   <tr>
    {{for ~root.players ~index=#index}}
        {{if ~index == #index}}
            <td>*</td>
        {{else}}
            <td>{{:~index}}+{{:#getIndex()}}</td>
        {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
   </tr>
{{/for}}
```